# laravel mysql 8 connection time out

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-connection, mysql-8.0

I'm a beginner at Laravel and configuring MySQL.

I have a VM with Laravel 5.6 and MySQL 8. I've configured MySQL so I can log in with MySQL Workbench and everything is working well, but when I try to do a query in Laravel I get an error:

> ```
> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (2002) 
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from `users`)
> ```

My VM has a static IP of `192.168.56.3` and DHCP `192.168.56.1`.
With MySQL Workbench I can connect with `192.168.56.3`, but in Laravel this IP gives me an error:

> ```
> PDOException (2006)
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
> ```

The other IP `192.168.56.1` gives me a timeout error.

My `.env` file is:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.56.3
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_db
DB_USERNAME=laravel_user
```

and my `.cnf` under `[mysqld]` is:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
tmpdir          = /tmp
#bind-address    = 192.168.56.3
```

Comment: Trying to connect to your DHCP Server (192.168.56.1) as if it were a MySQL Server will of course not work

Comment: Is WorkBench also installed inside the VM?

Comment: no, Workbench is in host machine

Comment: So how have you configured Laravel to connect to the database

Comment: I would guess it should be using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as Laravel and MySQL are on the same machine

Comment: I've updated with .env data

Comment: Try `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` because both Laravel and MySQL are on the same Machine (VM) and `127.0.0.1` says _This Machine_

Comment: I've just tried  but same result: MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Should I assume that you have checked that MySQL Server has actully been started?

Comment: yes, mysql is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been a while but I've found the answer. Use the following command to update your password with new authentication plugin. You can use MySQL 8 now. Have fun.

```
ALTER USER `username`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
```

OR

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```